# Cannot load a JSON file correctly in Python (2 to 5 GB size)

Tags: json, python-3.x

I tried to work on it for hours and still cannot find a solution. I am not familiar with JSON and hope someone can help me to figure out what's going on.

My computer ram is 32 GB and using Python 3.x. The files are between 2 and 5 GB and they all have the same issues. I tried to work on the smallest file first with this code:

```
import json


filename = 'Table.json'
with open(filename) as table:
    data = json.load(table, strict = False)
```

The code started working and until a few seconds later, it shows **"JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 60608660 column 3 (char 2366066673)"**. I also checked with Glogg and found it can only open this file till line 60608660 and it shows "US-ASCII" as the format on the top at Glogg (perhaps the file is incomplete and just cut off at line 60608660, is it???)

I also tried another way to load this file line by line based on a solution I found on Stack Overflow:

```
data = []
filename = 'Table.json'
with open(filename) as table:
    for line in table: 
        if line.strip(): 
            data.append(json.loads(line,strict = False))
```

And it's not working and says **"JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)"**.

My JASON files all look like:

```
[
    {
        "column 1" : 1,
        "column 2" : "OOOOOOOO",
        "column 3" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "column 4" : null,
        ....
        "column 100" : XXXX
     } 
     {
        "column 1" : 2,
        "column 2" : "OOOOOOOO",
        "column 3" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "column 4" : XYZ1235,
        ....
        "column 100" : XXXX
     }

     (same structure repeating N times)

     {
        "column 1" : N,
        "column 2" : "OOOOOOOO",
        "column 3" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "column 4" : abcd1234,
        ....
        "column 100" : XXXX
     }

]
```

What makes me confused is the first method can load at least till line 60608660 but the second method cannot even load line 2? Does that mean my JSON file is incomplete? Or, I need to encode and decode (I don't know what's the best way to do).

Did I miss anything? Thank you all in advance.

PS: all three JSON files gave me similar results. I am now working on the smallest file.

Comment: Did you try to open the file in some editor like Vim in Linux and check what is the line 60608660 ?
Vim will open til 3gb if i'm not wrong, but you can increase this value based on the system you are using.

Comment: Use `tail -n 5 Table.json` (Linux) or `Get-Content Table.json -Tail 5` (Windows, Powershell) to examine the last few lines of each file.  If your files cut off, then they're not valid json and you won't be able to parse them.  How were the files generated?

Comment: @deepcell, not yet. I am not familiar with Linux. The reason I tried to use Python to read and extract data from these JSON files is that all the CSV files I got from other team was misaligned. The misalignment caused a lot of issues. That's why I tried to work on these JSON files. Also, the other team doesn't know how to fix the misalignment issue....but I know those CSV files carries all the data from JSON.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, not sure about how they generated the files. This is my first week on this job. The data engineer team is on vacation now. I am going to try the method you provided. Thank you all.

Comment: @mimibao1009 you didn't specified you were on windows, ok. as Patrick stated above `Get-Content` using powershell, it should tell you if the json file is corrupted or not. Try.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, Thank yo so much! I found one file (the smallest one is incomplete) but the largest one is complete. Does that mean I should try streaming not jason.load for a 5GB file?

Comment: wrt/ the "second method":  you cannot parse json this way, period. `json.loads()` needs a full json document.

Comment: And for huge json files (not a good idea actually), you can use a streaming parser like ijson or jsonslicer etc.

Comment: @deepcell, sorry for missing information. I am working on Windows and just check my file with Powershell. It seems the smallest one is incomplete (and that's why). But the large files (5GB) are complete.  I guess the main issue is the JSON file is corrupted. I will contact the team generated the file when they come back. As for the large file.....I will keep trying.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thank you. I am going to read the instruction about ijson and jsonslicer.

Comment: @mimibao1009 for the large one you should parse the file into chunks. if possible when generating the json files, limit the size for something easily readable and add some extension to the file like .001, .002, and so on..

Comment: @deepcell, thank you again. I will try to pare the file into chunks, especially I know there will be some files over 10 GB..... I don't know why they keep producing large JSON files. But without clean data, I just cannot start to work on statistical analysis which is my real assignment.

Comment: Hello all, I tried ijson for the 5GB and it works! Thank you all so much!